# How I can parse xml in inno scripting

Tags: inno-setup

I want to parse an xml file in my inno setup script. Inno uses pascal scripting language.I didn't find out the way to actually parse the xml in pascal. I googled it a lot but all my efforts doesn't resulted fruitfully. Can it be possible to use libxml (xml parsing library for C language) in pascal. can anyone let me know how to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There are no Built in XML Routines in the [Pascal Support Functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm).

You could use MsXml [COM Object](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptautomation.htm), but since that may not be installed I would avoid that solution.

The other option would be to [import a DLL](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm) that provided the functionality you required.
The DLL can be written in any language.